# XSD - keyref in complexeType - No match found

Tags: xml, xsd, keyref

I write an XSD to define followin elements:

- glossary

  - definition [term=unique]

    - term [ref=term]

"Glossary" contains a list of "definition". Each "definition" has an unique attribute "term". A "definition" can contain mixed text with elements "term". Each "term" has an attribute "ref" that refers to a definition's term attribute.

Please, note that `keyref` (named "termRef") is a part of a `complexType` definition (named "textType"), because this type should be useful in several places of the xsd document, not only in "definition".

I do not understand why XML linter does not find the key reference.

Here is the code I have written:

XSD:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="foo"
        xmlns="foo"
        xmlns:xsfoo="foo"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="textType" mixed="true">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="term" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:normalizedString">
                            <xs:attribute name="ref" use="required" type="xs:token"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:keyref name="termRef" refer="glossaryTermUnique">
                    <xs:selector xpath="."/>
                    <xs:field xpath="@ref"/>
                </xs:keyref>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="glossary">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="definition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:complexContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="textType">
                                            <xs:attribute name="term" use="required" type="xs:token"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:complexContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="glossaryTermUnique">
                        <xs:selector xpath="xsfoo:definition"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@term"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo
        xmlns="foo"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="foo/none.xsd">
    <glossary>
        <definition term="ik 1">identification key 1</definition>
        <definition term="ik 2">identification key 2 with <term ref="ik 1">a ik 1 reference</term></definition>
    </glossary>
</foo>
```

Here is the error message from xmllint:

> Schemas validity error : Element '{foo}term': No match found for key-sequence ['ik 1'] of keyref '{foo}termRef'.

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the nesting of the elements in the XSD matters, Xerces says

> Identity Constraint error:  the keyref identity constraint "termRef"
> refers to a key or unique that is out of scope.

while

```
               <xs:unique name="glossaryTermUnique">
                    <xs:selector xpath="xsfoo:definition"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="@term"/>
                </xs:unique>
                <xs:keyref name="termRef" refer="glossaryTermUnique">
                    <xs:selector xpath="xsfoo:definition/xsfoo:term"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="@ref"/>
                </xs:keyref>
```

fixes that it seems.

Comment: Effectively, when I move the `keyref` after the `unique` definition, the xml is validated. However, that means the `keyref` does not belong to `textType` definition anymore. It should be a part of it, otherwise we have to duplicated `keyref` definition each time we use a `textType` in the xsd. (And, I wonder if the same error will not appear for the other usages not next to the unique.)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the answer before, nesting seems to be the key.

To solve the problem of reusability of "textType", we can move `keyref` into "foo" definition with the following xpath for the selector: `.//xsfoo:term`. So, the definition of "textType" is splitted (so, maybe not semantically correct?), but it works.

Full XSD:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="foo"
        xmlns="foo"
        xmlns:xsfoo="foo"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="textType" mixed="true">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="term" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:normalizedString">
                            <xs:attribute name="ref" use="required" type="xs:token"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="glossary">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="definition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:complexContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="textType">
                                            <xs:attribute name="term" use="required" type="xs:token"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:complexContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="glossaryTermUnique">
                        <xs:selector xpath="xsfoo:definition"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@term"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:keyref name="termRef" refer="glossaryTermUnique">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//xsfoo:term"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@ref"/>
        </xs:keyref>

    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```